# Having a problem with win condition checking and cpu input for Tic Tac Toe game in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Whenever there are 3 in a row (no matter if X or O), it returns me winning the game (e.g. X | O | X). I think it has something to do with my placePiece method but I can't quite put my finger on it. Could someone please help me find out what's wrong with my logic before I rip my hair out some more?

I sometimes also run into another problem when it's my first turn and I input a number to place, the computer will also input the same number and place it above mine. This only happens during the first turn, however, and never occurs again. I think it's because there's nothing in the playerPositions ArrayList at the beginning of the game. The computer input and the user input must be happening at the same time or maybe the computer is actually inputting before the user? I'm not too sure, but I have been stuck on these problems for quite some time now. Please help me :(

```
public class TicTacToe {
static ArrayList<Integer> playerPositions = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<Integer> cpuPositions = new ArrayList<>();
public static void main (String[] args) {
    //initializing the gameboard
    char[][] gameBoard = {
            {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
            {'-', '+', ' ', '+', '-'},
            {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
            {'-', '+', ' ', '+', '-'},
            {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}
    };
    //printing the gameboard which takes in a char array as the parameters
    printGameBoard(gameBoard);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Would you like to be X or O?");
    char user = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
    char cpu = ' ';
    if (user == 'x') {
        cpu = 'o';
    } else {
        cpu = 'x';
    }
    // while (true) loops code indefinitely
    while (true) {
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Your move! (1-9): ");
        int pos = scan.nextInt();
        //checking if the pos you entered is already in the array list or
        // if you are trying to take a position taken by the computer already
        while(playerPositions.contains(pos) || cpuPositions.contains(playerPositions)) {
            System.out.println("Position is already taken... Enter another position: ");
            pos = scan.nextInt();
        }
        //placepiece by taking in the initial char[][], getting the int pos from scanner, and getting the char user from scanner
        placePiece(gameBoard, pos, user);
        //checking the result after you place a piece
        String result = winnerWinnerChickenDinner();
        //checking if there even is a result after every time you place a piece
        if (result.length()>0) {
            System.out.println(result);
            break;
        }


        Random rand = new Random();
        int cpuPos = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
        placePiece(gameBoard, cpuPos, cpu);
        //checking if the number the computer generated is already taken by you or if the computer already generated that position
        while(playerPositions.contains(cpuPos) || cpuPositions.contains(cpuPos)) {
            cpuPos = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
        }

        printGameBoard(gameBoard);
        //checking result after cpu places a piece
        result = winnerWinnerChickenDinner();
        //checking if there is a result or just an empty string
        if (result.length()>0) {
            System.out.println(result);
            break;
        }
    }
}
public static void printGameBoard(char[][] gameBoard){
    //for each row in the gameboard
    for(char[] row : gameBoard) {
        //for each character in the row
        for(char c : row) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
        //printing a line for each row
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public static void placePiece(char[][] gameBoard, int pos, char user) {
    //initializing the char
    char symbol = ' ';
    //checking if the person chose x or not
    if(user == 'x') {
        symbol = 'X';
        playerPositions.add(pos);
    } else {
        cpuPositions.add(pos);
    }
    if (user == 'o') {
        symbol = 'O';
        playerPositions.add(pos);
    } else {
        cpuPositions.add(pos);
    }
    switch (pos) {
        case 1:
            gameBoard[0][0] = symbol;
            break;
            // [0][1] is the space for the line '|'
        case 2:
            gameBoard[0][2] = symbol;
            break;
        case 3:
            gameBoard[0][4] = symbol;
            break;
        case 4:
            gameBoard[2][0] = symbol;
            break;
        case 5:
            gameBoard[2][2] = symbol;
            break;
        case 6:
            gameBoard[2][4] = symbol;
            break;
        case 7:
            gameBoard[4][0] = symbol;
            break;
        case 8:
            gameBoard[4][2] = symbol;
            break;
        case 9:
            gameBoard[4][4] = symbol;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
public static String winnerWinnerChickenDinner(){
    List topRow = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List midRow = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);
    List botRow = Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9);
    //list goes from left to right so have to make them top to bottom
    List leftCol = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 7);
    List midCol = Arrays.asList(2, 5, 8);
    List rightCol = Arrays.asList(3, 6, 9);
    //same for diagonals
    List leftRightDia = Arrays.asList(1, 5, 9);
    List rightLeftDia = Arrays.asList(3, 5, 7);
    //List of a list... adding lists above to wincon list
    List<List> winCon = new ArrayList<List>();
    winCon.add(topRow);
    winCon.add(midRow);
    winCon.add(botRow);
    winCon.add(leftCol);
    winCon.add(midCol);
    winCon.add(rightCol);
    winCon.add(leftRightDia);
    winCon.add(rightLeftDia);
    for (List l : winCon) {
        if (playerPositions.containsAll(l)) {
            return "You won!";
        } else if (cpuPositions.containsAll(l)) {
            return "A computer that randomly generates numbers won...";
        } else if (playerPositions.size() + cpuPositions.size() == 9){
            return "Tie";
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

}

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we ask questions for very specific problemys, and help each other to find solutions. You have put all your code as a question - it is very wide and has many parts. Try to divide your code into chunks and see which part is not working. Try to test every chunk of your code(see if it brings desired results). After you will find the chunk which is problematic then post the question only about this part. Write what is the desired output which you expect. Try also to look for similar question, maybe someone already had same issue befre? :) Good luck:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your code. But first, I haven't seen for a long time a GUI made in console, haha (it looks really nice).

1) `cpuPositions.contains(playerPositions)` should be `cpuPositions.contains(pos)` (first while loop)

2)  The

```
if (user == 'o') {
    symbol = 'O';
        playerPositions.add(pos);
} else {
        cpuPositions.add(pos);
} 
if (user == 'x') .... etc.
```

is not working correctly. One solution could be modifying the `char user` parameter to `String user` and make these modifications:

1. `placePiece(gameBoard, cpuPos, "cpu",cpu);`
2. `placePiece(gameBoard, pos, "user",user);`
3. `placePiece(char[][] gameBoard, int pos, String user, char playerSymbol)`

Now the implementation of this method could be this:

```
char symbol = Character.toUpperCase(playerSymbol);
if (user.equals("user")) {
        playerPositions.add(pos);
    } else {
        cpuPositions.add(pos);
} 
// rest of the method
```

3) You check if the generated CPU position is taken **AFTER** you've already placed the piece:

```
placePiece(gameBoard, cpuPos, cpu);
while (playerPositions.contains(cpuPos) || cpuPositions.contains(cpuPos)) {
      cpuPos = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
}
```

The result is : cpu position can override its positions or yours. Solution: call the `placePiece()` method after the `while` loop.

4) There are a lot of cases you don't check before you initialize the user and cpu.

What if I write "random" when I'm asked to pick "x" or "o" ?  - the program won't work correctly

What if I write "X" instead of "x" when I'm asked to pick "x" or "o" ? - the program won't work correctly

5) Add type parameter to your `List`s

`List<Integer>` instead of `List`

6) You should check for list size outside the for loop. Otherwise, if you're having a situation like :

X 0 X

X X 0

0 0 X

The program will return "TIE" because in the first iteration, the checked list will be {1,2,3} (`topRow`) and none of the first 2 `if`s will be executed but the last with `(playerPositions.size() + cpuPositions.size() == 9)` is correct technically so it returns "TIE" which is not correct.

```
for (List l : winCon) {
     if (playerPositions.containsAll(l)) {
         return "You won!";
     } else if (cpuPositions.containsAll(l)) {
         return "A computer that randomly generates numbers won...";
     }
}
if (playerPositions.size() + cpuPositions.size() == 9) {
    return "Tie";
}
return "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your placePiece method adds the position to both lists, regardless of the symbol.
This is because of how you have set up the if statements in the method.

If the input char is 'x', then it will add the position to the playerPositions, but when it checks if the input is 'o', it will also add the position to the cpuPositions. Something similar happens if the input char is 'o'.

Try rewriting the method like this:

```
// Change the method signature so it includes a boolean describing who is using the method
public static void placePiece(char[][] gameBoard, int pos, char symbol, boolean isUser) {
    // Change the symbol to the right character
    if (symbol == 'x') {
        symbol = 'X';
    } else if (symbol == 'o') {
        symbol = 'O';
    } else {
        symbol = ' ';
    }
    // Now put the position in the right list
    if (isUser) {
        playerPositions.add(pos);
    } else {
        cpuPositions.add(pos);
    }
    // Keep the other code the same
    switch(pos):
        case 1:
            gameBoard[0][0] = symbol;
    ...
```

This fixes part of the problem, but there is another bug. You do check that the cpu position is not already taken, but you call placePositions before you update the position. So the code in main() needs to be changed as follows:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int cpuPos = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
    //checking if the number the computer generated is already taken by you or if the computer already generated that position
    while (playerPositions.contains(cpuPos) || cpuPositions.contains(cpuPos)) {
        cpuPos = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
    }
    // calling this after cpuPos is updated (note this uses the updated placePiece method signature)
    placePiece(gameBoard, cpuPos, cpu, false); // false signifies this is for the CPU
```

Note you will need to change the other use of placePiece similarly; i.e. change it from `placePiece(gameBoard, pos, user);` to `placePiece(gameBoard, pos, user, true);`